# Prove that the greatest lower bound of $F$ (in the subset partial order) is $\cap F$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, order-theory

This is one of the question I'm working on:

> Suppose $A$ is a set, $F \subseteq \mathbb{P(A)}$, and $F \neq
>  \emptyset$. Then prove that the greatest lower bound of $F$ (in the
>    subset partial order) is $\cap F$.

Now this is my attempt at this problem:

We know that $\cap F$ is a lower bound of F since $\forall X \in F (\cap F \subseteq$ X). Now we need to prove that this is the greatest lower bound of $F$.

Now I'm stuck here. How to show that it is the greatest lower bound ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Show it directly from the definition of *greatest lower bound*. Suppose that $L$ is a lower bound for $F$. Then $L\subseteq X$ for each $X\in F$. What can you say about the relationship between $L$ and $\bigcap F$?

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to show that $L \subseteq \cap F$. But I cannot understand why it has to be true.  Let's take an example of $A = \{1,2\}, F = \{ \{2 \}, \{1,2\}\}$. Now $L \subseteq \cap F$ is not true because $\{1,2\}$ is not a subset of $\{2\}$.

Comment: @Sibi: But $\{1,2\}$ is not a lower bound for $F$ at all, so it’s irrelevant. The only lower bounds for that $F$ are $\varnothing$ and $\{2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

∩F is the smallest element in the subset partial order ( as you pointed out  ∀X∈F(∩F⊆ X)). Therefore it is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: How is it smallest ? That's the thing I'm not able to understand.

Comment: Well, by definition: Suppose R is a partial order on a set A, B ⊆ A, and b ∈ B.
Then b is called an R-smallest element of B (or just a smallest element if R
is clear from the context) if ∀x ∈ B(bRx). Let S = {(X,Y)∈P(A)×P(A)| X⊆Y}. Then by the definition above, Y∈F is the smallest-S element of F if ∀X∈F(YSX), or in other words∀X∈F(Y⊆X) . But you have already pointed out that ∀X∈F(∩F⊆ X).